# Raspberry Pi button bug, what is happening?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, gpiozero, debug

I am new user of raspberry pi. I have two buttons, and some code to run, yet the led will not react to the buttons. It's probably a easy fix, but keep in mind, I am new to robotic and have only started programming 2 years ago, so I might need some dumbed down responses. Any help is appreciated.[image: My wiring.(I know it sucks.)] [image]

[image]
If you cannot see the gpio pins here is a text version. The commas are where the cords connect. ..,.......,......... 
 next row of gpio              .,,.................

Comment: Does the following light the LED?  `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs w 25 1`

Comment: @robotechnology, couple things ... `1` when you post a code listing, do not post a picture of text, post the text itself ... that way your code can be copied and tested ... use the `{}` button to format the code so that it is readable in the web browser ....... `2` you can delete your own comments so that your post is not cluttered ......... `3` use this to refer to pins https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: So the LED is wired correctly.  Now check the buttons by `pigs r 2 r 3` to read buttons 2 and 3.  Try with and without the buttons pressed.  Do they change?  At a guess I'd say one or both sticks at 1.

Comment: GPIO 2 and 3 both happen to have external pulls to 3V3 fitted.  That means they will always read high unless the other end of the switch is connected to ground (0V).

Comment: @joan Can you clarify? Can you use the wring picture thing and tell me what to do and what I did wrong? I Don't understand the terms you are using. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, then should they be connected to another type of gpio, or should I make the other end of the switch connected to ground? How do I do that?

Comment: @robotechnology If you have another question, ask another question *as a question* via the [Ask Question page](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  Adding comments here will not be noticed by anyone (unless you address them `@who`, but that specific person may well never reply).  *This **is not** a discussion forum.*

Comment: ok thx goldilocks